# iptables OUTPUT DNAT not working

Tags: iptables, openwrt

I tried to do something similar to this question

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85933/20426

So I want to make all out-going traffic to port 44444 redirected to 1.1.1.1:80

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 44444 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:80
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 44444 -j LOG --log-prefix
```

However the traffic is still going to original IP, not `1.1.1.1:80`

I am trying to setup it on my OpenWRT router, verison is:

```
MTK OpenWrt SDK V3.4
revision : e7847192
benchmark : APSoC SDK 5.0.1.0
Linux 3.10.14
iptables v1.4.21
```

Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: You've described what you've done, but you haven't described any actual problem.  Does it work, is it doing what you expected?  Have you tried monitoring the interface(s) with tcpdump or wireshark to see if the packets are being redirected?

Comment: @cas sorry, my problem is traffic was **NOT** going to 1.1.1.1:80. Nothing seemed to work. I am using tcpdump in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

```
# iptables -tnat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 44444 -j DNAT --to-destination $someip:8888
$ nc $someotherip 44444
# tcpdump -n ...
18:23:54.699942 IP [my ip].55212 > [someip].8888: Flags [S], seq 1138760196, ...
```

If I understand this part of the [iptables man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html) correctly, `OUTPUT` only applies to connections that originate from the host itself, *not* routed connections. Are you sure you don't want to put the rule in `PREROUTING`?

> `nat`:
>         This  table is consulted when a packet that creates a new connection is encountered.  It consists of four built-ins: ..., `OUTPUT` (for altering  locally-generated  packets  before  routing),  and
>         `POSTROUTING` (for altering packets as they are about to go out).

Comment: Oh, it seems I didn't grasp the meaning of OUTPUT. I switched to PREROUTING and it  works. Thanks.