# iptables blocking local traffic

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, ufw, netfilter

*My local machine IP: 192.168.0.35*

**What I did:** [Answer that i tried here!!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85932/how-can-i-redirect-outbound-traffic-to-port-80-using-iptables-locally/487888#487888)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.35:80
```

**The error:**

Now I can not access any more IP's from my local machine and I do not know why it happened.

Any IP that is: 123.123.123.123, etc ... The result of any attempt is the default page "Apache2 Debian Default Page". Now I can't access my router page to make changes in port forwarding. I don't know how undo this `iptables` command.

---

**What i want:**

I was looking for a way to: Expose my Webserver, from the router on the Internet over port 80 and 443. Deploy `httpd`(apache2) on port 1337 and continue dev on 8000,8080. From my router to my Raspbian, I'm trying to:

> INTERNET IPx:80,443<===>80,443 router <===> IP-local-web-httpd (raspbian):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful using iptables command.

To have access again you have to delete the iptables command you performed.

So do with -D option and not -A to undo the command.

sudo iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.35:80